# Multiple classes in one tag (jquery and css)

Tags: jquery, html, css

My HTML page is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="hv1 bck">Vedios</a>
<div class="hva1"></div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.css page is as under:

```
.bck{background:red; color:green;}
```

My js.js page is as under:

```
$('[class=hv1]').hover(function(){$('[class=hva1]').html('Free video tutorials');});
```

Above example is to describe my concern, indeed I am trying to write multiple classes assigned as one for CSS and one for jquery in one tag which unfortunately do not work, however if I write those as single one by one or in separate tags then they work, is there any solution for writing classes for both in one tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It is perfectly valid for an element to have multiple classes. Incidentally, jQuery uses a dot for [class selection](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), e.g. `$('.hv1')`.

Comment: Yes it is valid to have multiple classes but when you write one class which has been used in jquery and one class which has been used in css as shown in above example (.hv1 and .bck) then it does not work.

Comment: I don't have any issue with html or css or jquery, my only concern is that I am not able to use multiple classes in one tag in above case

Comment: I think I understand. If you use the appropriate jQuery [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the jQuery selector `[name="value"]` that:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

If you change to `[name~="value"]` it will alter the selection to:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

For additional selectors please see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: It has partially solved the concern now hv1 class is working but bck class is not working, I want both to work in one tag

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is fine, you can add two classes with a space as you are:

```
<a href="#" class="hv1 bck">Vedios</a>
```

Your JS can simply look for either of those two classes `.hv1` or `.bck`:

```
$('.hv1').hover(function(){
  $('.hva1').html('Free video tutorials');
});
```

or both if you wanted:

```
$('.hv1.bck').hover(function(){
  $('.hva1').html('Free video tutorials');
});
```

Unless you're trying to do something differently then what it appears, there is no reason you can't just specifically call the name of the `class`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2jspevL/)

Comment: Are you responding a clearly defined issue? What are you trying to solve? I ask because I can't determine the OP's problem.

Comment: It appears OP is having an issue targeting an element with 2 classes. His/her code does not work in this case he/she can very simply target `.classname`